# PHP === vs !===

Tags: php

When it comes to this function, everything seems to work alright

```
function found($in,$find){
    if(strpos($in,$find) !== false)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

if(found("Sample text","text"))
    echo 'Found 1';
if(found("Sample text","house"))
    echo 'Found 2';
```

Result:

> Found 1

But, if I use === I just do not get the right results:

```
function found($in,$find){
    if(strpos($in,$find) === true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

if(found("Sample text","text"))
    echo 'Found 1';
else
    echo 'Not found';
if(found("Sample text","house"))
    echo 'Found 2';
else
    echo 'Not found';
```

Result:

> Not foundNot found

Both return false

Why is that?

Comment: `strpos` returns an integer, not a boolean.

Comment: `strpos()` returns `false` if not found and the position if found so it will never `=== true` but it will `== true` if the position is not 0.

Comment: Because the strpos() function returns either a Boolean false, or an integer >= 0.... a Boolean true is never returned under any circumstance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

function [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) never returns true.

It returns integer being the index of the first occurance of the needle, and if the needle doesn't occur it returns boolean false.

Answer (score 4):

`===` checks the type as well, `strpos` returns an integer (except it returns false if the needle was not found) and you are comparing it to boolean true.

Comment: not true. strpos returns INT and boolean. (Just not boolean true)